# Vuex reset store variable when switching route

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to create a method that brings you back to prevoius route and then resets variable that is stored in vuex.
So far I tried doing this:
 (In the componentfrom template):

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" @click="bar">Back</button>`

In the component script:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

methods: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'movies'
        ]),
     bar () {
           this.$router.go(-1)
            this.movies=[]
        }
}
```

And my vuex store:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        movies : []
    },
    getters: {
        movies: state => {
            return state.movies
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        mutateArray: (state, payload) => {
            state.movies = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        updateArray({commit}, payload ){
            commit('mutateArray', payload)
         }
    }
})
```

Clicking the button brings me to previous route but it seems that the `movies` state variable is not empty (as there are things displayed on that route indicting its not empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating state in an incorrect way. What you need is to call the updateArray action with empty payload. In your bar method, it can look something like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateArray',[]);
```

Note that this is not not the only solution on how to call an action. For more info visit the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I think I could also import and map action updateArray an then call it `this.updateArray([])`

Comment: Sure, that is also possible. Depends on your preference.

Comment: Actually I dont mind any of those I just wonder which one is better in terms of writing style

Comment: I personally use dispatch when having 1-2 action calls per component and mapActions for more.